# in w3m the lines on some webpages don't fit (practically any) terminal window

Tags: w3m

For instance on [this page](https://www.makemkv.com/developers/usage.txt) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230730115807/https://www.makemkv.com/developers/usage.txt)) the text extends to infinity, w3m doesn't wrap the lines at all for unknown reasons. lynx in comparison isn't affected.

I can only read by scrolling the affected lines using the w3m cursor. Depending on the size of my terminal window the lines are cut off in this manner:

> --progress=file
> Output all progress messages to file. The same special file names as in --messages are recognized with

when I'd expect the lines to be wrapped — the full paragraph:

> --progress=file
> Output all progress messages to file. The same special file names as in --messages are recognized with additional value "-same" to output to the same file as messages. Naturally --progress should follow --messages in this case. Default
> is no output.

Is this by design or a clear bug?

---

```
w3m version w3m/0.5.3+git20230121, options lang=en,m17n,image,color,ansi-color,mouse,gpm,menu,cookie,ssl,ssl-verify,external-uri-loader,w3mmailer,nntp,gopher,ipv6,alarm,mark
```

[This superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/1208352/fold-wrap-long-lines-in-w3m) isn't a duplicate, the OP is attempting to configure a fixed line length.

Comment: That's the correct behaviour for a text file. If there's no newline character, it's a single line.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I didn't remember that this was a `.txt` file, as likely were all pages I referred to.